# Not registering wireless adapter / kali on virtualbox

Tags: linux, kali-linux

ifconfig wlan0 returns a 
`wlan0: error fetching interface information: device not found`

I am using a TP-LINK TL-WN722N on Kali Linux in Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the adaptor isn't passed trough Virtualbox. Here are some possible solutions:

Install Virtualbox tools and use USB-passtrough in Virtualbox.

OR

Live boot Kali Linux. The advantage is that you don't have to worry about virtualisation and you can keep your disk unmodified. A tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install).
You can also install a Linux distro alongside Windows. A tutorial for that can be found [here](http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows).